# c++ heap memory allocation/deallocation

Tags: c++

If i declare something on the heap like `char *a=new char[1000]` and the main program stops what will happen with that allocated memory if there is no `delete[]` call? It remains on the heap or is automatic deallocated?

Comment: A bit of terminology: you **declare** and **define** names, like `a` here. You **allocate** objects on the heap. Well, formally, the "free store", but nobody calls it that.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727383/dynamically-allocated-memory-after-program-termination

Comment: @PeteBecker: may I quote that in my user info, for reference when people do that "C++ has no heap so I refuse to answer your question" thing?

Answer (score 8):

As far as C++ is concerned, what will happen to it is totally undefined. However, pretty much any reasonable operating system will clean up the memory allocated by a process when it has terminated. It is, however, a very good practice to clean up after yourself.

Answer (score 2):

What the C++ standard specifies "ends" shortly after you return from `main()` - it does explain that global objects are destroyed at some point after this, `atexit()` and some other "we're quitting" level functions also get run after `main` returns. But what happens to the memory that your program lives in is not specified by the C++ standard. The same applies to the contents of the heap.

It is up to the OS to clear up the application, if there is an OS in the system (C++ doesn't specify that you have to have an OS either).

Answer (score 0):

Normaly it will be cleard up by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

When your application crashes or gets aborted for whatever reason, the OS reclaims the memory in normal case. But,this is undefined.