# Is ending a program without releasing all dynamically allocated resources risky?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, dynamic-allocation

I know that stack allocated resources are released in reverse order as they were allocated at the end of a function as part of RAII. I've been working on a project and I allocate a lot of memory with "new" from a library I'm using, and am testing stuff out. I haven't added a shutdown function as a counterpart to the initialise function that does all the dynamic allocation. When you shut down the program I'm pretty sure there is no memory leak as the allocated memory should be reclaimed by the operating system. At least any modern OS, as explained in this question similar to mine: [dynamically allocated memory after program termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727383/dynamically-allocated-memory-after-program-termination) .

I'm wondering two things:

1: Is there a particular order that resources are released in in this case? Does it have anything to do with your written code (ie., which order you allocated it), or is it completely up to the OS to do its thing?

2: The reason I haven't made a shutdown function to reverse the initialisation is because I say to myself I'm just testing stuff now, I'll do it later. Is there any risk of doing any damage to anything by doing what I'm doing? The worse I can imagine is what was mentioned in the answer to that question I linked, and that is that the OS fails to reclaim the memory and you end up with a memory leak even after the program exits.

I've followed the Bullet physics library tutorial and initialise a bunch of code like this:

```
pSolver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;
pOverlappingPairCache = new btDbvtBroadphase();
pCollisionConfig = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
pDispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(pCollisionConfig);
pDynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(pDispatcher, pOverlappingPairCache, pSolver, pCollisionConfig);
```

And never call delete on any of it at the moment because, as I said, I'm just testing.

Comment: There is no risk unless you use something the OS says persists after the process, eg shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the resources. Open files will be closed. Memory will be freed. Destructors will not be called. Temporary files created will not be deleted.

There is no risk of having a memory leak after the program exits.

Answer (score 1):

Because programs can crash, there are many mechanisms in place preventing a process to leak after it stopped and leaking usually isn't that bad.

As a matter of fact, if you have a lot of allocations that you don't delete until the end of the program, it can be faster to just have the kernel clean up after you.

However destructors are not run. This mostly causes temporary files to not be deleted.
Also it makes debugging actual memory leaks more difficult.

I suggest using [`std::unique_ptr<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and not leaking in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the memory is *actually* allocated and on your host system.

If you are only working with classes that don't override `operator new()`  AND you are using a modern operating system that guarantees memory resources are released when the process exits, then all dynamically allocated memory should be released when your program terminates.    There is no guarantee on the order of memory release (e.g. objects will not be released in the same order, or in reverse order, of their construction).    The only real risk in this case is associated with bugs in the host operating system that cause resources of programs/processes to be improperly managed   (which is a low risk - but not zero risk - for user programs in modern windows or unix OSs).

If you are using any classes that override `operator new()`  (i.e. that change how raw memory is allocated in the process of dynamically constructing an object) then the risk depends on how memory is actually being allocated - and what the requirements are for deallocation.    For example, if the `operator new()` uses global or system-wide resources (e.g. mutexes, semaphores, memory that is shared between processes) then there is a risk that your program will not properly release those resources, and then indirectly cause problems for other programs which use the same resources.    In practice, depending on the design of such a class, the needed cleanup might be in a destructor, an `operator delete()` or some combination of the two - but, however it is done, your program will need to explicitly release such objects (e.g. a `delete` expression that corresponds to the `new` expression) to ensure the global resources are properly released.

One risk is that destructors of your dynamically allocated objects will not be invoked.   If your program relies on the destructor doing anything other than release dynamically allocated memory (presumably allocated by the class constructor and managed by other member functions) then the additional clean-up actions will not be performed.

If your program will ever be built and run on a host system that doesn't have a modern OS then there is no guarantee that dynamically allocated memory will be reclaimed.

If code in your program will ever be reused in a larger long-running program  (e.g. your `main()` function is renamed, and then called from another program in a loop) then your code may cause that larger program to have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, since the operating system (unless it's some exotic or ancient OS) will not leak the memory after the process has ended. Same goes for sockets and file handles; they will be closed at process exit. It's not in good style to not clean up after yourself, but if you don't, there's no harm done to the overall OS environment.

However, in your example, it looks to me like the only memory that you would actually need to release yourself is that of `pDynamicsWorld`, since the others should be cleaned up by the `btDiscreteDynamicsWorld` instance. You're passing them as constructor arguments, and I suspect they get destroyed automatically when `pDynamicsWorld` gets destroyed. You should read the documentation to make sure.

However, it's just not in good style (because it's unsafe) to use `delete` anymore. So instead of using `delete` to destroy `pDynamicsWorld`, you can use a `unique_ptr` instead, which you can safely create using the `std::make_unique` function template:

```
#include <memory>

// ...

// Allocate everything else with 'new' here, as usual.
// ...

// Except for this one, which doesn't seem to be passed to another
// constructor.      
auto pDynamicsWorld = std::make_unique<btDiscreteDynamicsWorld>(
    pDispatcher, pOverlappingPairCache, pSolver, pCollisionConfig);
```

Now, `pDispatcher`, `pOverlappingPairCache`, `pSolver` and `pCollisionConfig` should be destroyed by `pDynamicsWorld` automatically, and `pDynamicsWorld` itself will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope because it's a `unique_ptr`.

But, again: **Read the documentation** of Bullet Physics to check whether the objects you pass as arguments to the constructors of the Bullet Physics classes actually do get cleaned up automatically or not.